# Mazda 3 Gear Shift and Gear Indicator

Tags: transmission, gears, mazda-3

I have a 2013 Mazda 3 i Grand Touring. I was driving today on the freeway. I had just exited one freeway onto another, and had to slow down a bit because of the car in front of me and the curve of the entrance. I shifted from 6th down to 5th, back up to 6th, then down to 5th because of a hill.

For some reason my gear shift indicator went out, but I was in manual mode, and the "M" that indicates this was still on. My car felt like it had shifted down to 4th at this point. So I tried shifting up; no luck. Tried switching back to automatic; still no luck. So I put my hazards on, got off to the shoulder, and slowed down. Once I had slowed to probably about 40 mph, the gear indicator came back on, and the started shifting as normal (still in automatic).

I restarted my car just to be safe, and cautiously accelerated to merge back onto the freeway. Everything was fine. Drove another 15 minutes, still good, even switched back to manual for a little and it was good.

At no point did any error lights come on. I did have an issue with m brake switch about 6 months ago, which was causing the gear to drop at high speeds. But that was diagnosed by the dealer as a broken brake switch. So they just replaced it and it was good.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Thanks.